# Why does my div not appear when using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div appear when I click a button. The div that I expect to appear is .photo1.
I have used just a block with a background colour for the fiddle but in reality it will be an image which will be made visible on click.
At the moment, nothing happens on click.

Many thanks for any help.

My code can be found at jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcy9999/WFuRX/)

The html is:

```
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="showStuff('photo1')";> show the block </a>
       </li>
    </menu>
    <span div id="photo1" style="display: none;">
        <brandinfobox class="photo1"> </brandinfobox>
    </span>
</body>
```

The javascript is:

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

The CSS is:

```
.menu {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: orange;
    background-size: 40, 130px;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
brandinfobox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 384px;
    width:620px;
}
.photo1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;;
    background-color:black;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: You’re opening an `<ul>` but closing `<menu>`, you write stuff like `<span div id="photo1"` – seriously, please learn some __HTML basics__ before continuing with anything else.

Comment: Use a debugger. Modern web-browsers have developer tools integrated. `"Uncaught ReferenceError: showStuff is not defined"` might be the cause why you are having problems (besides incorrect syntax)

Comment: In jsfiddle, change the second drop down on the top left to "no wrap" and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/WFuRX/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incredibly messy and I would recommend learning about HTML tags, CSS classes and IDs - specifically which you should be using where.

The reason it wasn't working, however was because the JavaScript function was being scoped (only accessible) on page load. Putting it in the head or body tag (in JSFiddle, through the menu on the left) will mean that the browser can find the `showStuff` function.

I have attempted to tidy up your uses of classes and tags in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/WFuRX/2/

Comment: I am currently trying to learn about everything mentioned above. I am completely new to this stuff. I appreciate that my code is very probably a complete mess. I am extremely thankful for your help. I will continue to read and practice. Seriously - thank you for taking the time to help me.